# How to calculate Big O of Dynamic programming (Memoization) algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, dynamic-programming

**How would I go about calculating the big O of a DP algorithm**. I've come to realize my methods for calculating algorithms doesn't always work. I would use simple tricks to extract what the Big O was. For example if I were evaluating the none memoized version of the algorithm below (removing the cache mechanism) I would look at the number of times the recursive method called itself in this case 3 times. I would then raise this value to n giving O(3^n). With DP that isn't right at all because the recursive stack doesn't go as deep. My intuition tells me that the Big O of the DP solution would be O(n^3). **How would we verbally explain how we came up with this answer**. **More importantly what is a technique that can be used to find the Big O of similar problems**. Since it is DP I'm sure the number of sub problems is important **how do we calculate the number of sub problems.**

```
public class StairCase {
    public int getPossibleStepCombination(int n) {
        Integer[] memo = new Integer[n+1];
        return getNumOfStepCombos(n, memo);
    }

    private int getNumOfStepCombos(int n, Integer[] memo) {
        if(n < 0) return 0;
        if(n == 0) return 1;
        if(memo[n] != null) return memo[n];
        memo[n] = getNumOfStepCombos(n - 1, memo) + getNumOfStepCombos(n - 2, memo) + getNumOfStepCombos(n-3,memo);
        return memo[n];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `3` lines do nothing but compare `int` values, access an array by index, and see if an `Integer` reference is `null`. Those things are all `O(1)`, so the only question is how many times the method is called recursively.

This question is very complicated, so I usually cheat. I just use a counter to see what's going on. (I've made your methods static for this, but in general you should avoid static mutable state wherever possible).

```
static int counter = 0;

public static int getPossibleStepCombination(int n) {
    Integer[] memo = new Integer[n+1];
    return getNumOfStepCombos(n, memo);
}

private static int getNumOfStepCombos(int n, Integer[] memo) {
    counter++;
    if(n < 0) return 0;
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    if(memo[n] != null) return memo[n];
    memo[n] = getNumOfStepCombos(n - 1, memo) + getNumOfStepCombos(n - 2, memo) + getNumOfStepCombos(n-3,memo);
    return memo[n];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        counter = 0;
        getPossibleStepCombination(i);
        System.out.print(i + " => " + counter + ", ");
    }
}
```

This program prints

```
0 => 1, 1 => 4, 2 => 7, 3 => 10, 4 => 13, 5 => 16, 6 => 19, 7 => 22, 8 => 25, 9 => 28,
```

so it looks like the final counter values are given by `3n + 1`.

In a more complicated example, I might not be able to spot the pattern, so I enter the first few numbers `(e.g. 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16)` into the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) and I usually get taken to a page containing a simple formula for the pattern.

Once you've cheated in this way to find out the rule, you can set about understanding why the rule works.

Here's how I understand where `3n + 1` comes from. For each value of `n` you only have to do the line

```
memo[n] = getNumOfStepCombos(n - 1, memo) + getNumOfStepCombos(n - 2, memo) + getNumOfStepCombos(n-3,memo);
```

**exactly once**. This is because we are recording the results and only doing this line if the answer has not already been calculated.

Therefore, when we start with `n == 5` we run that line **exacly 5 times**; once for `n == 5`, once with `n == 4`, once with `n == 3`, once with `n == 2` and once with `n == 1`. So that's `3 * 5 == 15` times the method `getNumOfStepCombos` gets called from itself. The method also gets called once from outside itself (from `getPossibleStepCombination`), so the total number of calls is `3n + 1`.

Therefore this is an `O(n)` algorithm.

If an algorithm has lines that are not `O(1)` this counter method cannot be used directly, but you can often adapt the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer is technically not wrong but is a bit misleading. We should be calculating big O notation by how the function responds to changes in input size. Paul's answer of O(n) makes the complexity appear to be linear time when it really is exponential to the number of bits required to represent the number n. So for example, n=10 has ~30 calculations and m=2 bits. n=100 has ~300 calculations and m=3 bits. n=1000 has ~3000 calculations and m=4 bits.

I believe that your function's complexity would be O(2^m) where m is number of bits needed to represent n. I referred to https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Knapsack-problem-NP-complete-even-when-it-has-complexity-O-nW for a lot of my answer.